# Table with start and end date. How to best get all rows active today?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of events, and each event has a start date and an end date. I'm trying to write a query that will get all of the events happening on a specific date. There are no times, just date, though I doubt this changes things enough to matter.

I'm sure the answer is simple, I've just been looking at this for too long and I'm drawing a complete blank. I'm using SQL Server, but would like something that would work everywhere if possible.

Comment: `select * from table where startdate >= getdate() and enddate() <= getdate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use date logic in the `where` clause:

```
select e.*
from events e
where start_date >= cast(getdate() as date) and
      end_date <= cast(getdate() as date)
```

You can substitute a constant value for the expression `cast(getdate() as date)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you could have events that are ongoing, you can use this:

```
DECLARE @SomeDay DATE

SET @SomeDay = CAST('01 JAN 2014' AS DATE)

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE 
(
    CAST(start_date AS DATE) <= CAST(@SomeDay AS DATE) AND
    (
        CAST(end_date AS DATE) >= CAST(@SomeDay AS DATE) OR 
        end_date IS NULL
    )
)
```